Getting accurate Uncertainty from MFVI?
I wanted to know if there has been any research on methods to improve the accuracy of Mean-Field Variantional Inference (which doesn't discard the mean-field approximation). Apparently it is known to under-estimate uncertainty and I understand that is because it is a unimodal approximation to Bayesian Inference.
But I'm wondering particularly in the context of Bayesian Deep learning if perhaps there are post-processing calibration methods (e.g. fitting a linear model to transform the predictions) that make Bayesian High-Density-Intervals (or Bayesian credible intervals) reasonably accurate?

Check out
Giordano, R. J., T. Broderick, and M. I. Jordan. 2015. “Linear Response Methods for Accurate Covariance Estimates from Mean Field Variational Bayes.” In Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems, 1441–9.

Will do! Thanks

@JohnMadden I'm concerned that this method relies on the covariance matrix which is intractible for deep learning.
